# Resizing elements based on container height pure CSS

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I am attempting to have the first section of my page be 100% of the user's window, while having 3 vertical items resize depending on the height of the screen.

To achieve this I am using flexbox, specifically these styles:

**CSS**

```
.vertical-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 100%;
}

.theitems {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

This does work, but for some odd reason it only will resize the elements correctly in Firefox. Safari stretches the image and Chrome doesn't resize at all. I thought that the flex specifications I gave (`flex-grow: 1`) would resize the items so that they all fit within the container vertically.

**Firefox (Correct)**

[image]

**Chrome (Incorrect)**

[image]

**Safari (Incorrect)**

[image]

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ads7hbvr/10/)**

Does anybody have any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing two rules that don't work well together.

You've given the container `justify-content: space-between`.

But you've also given each flex item `flex-grow: 1`.

If each item is set to consume all available space, `justify-content: space-between` does nothing (there's no space to distribute).

Pick one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use vh?

```
height: 100vh //This is 100% of the viewport
```

Then you can give elements inside 33.33vh